# Why is this question not being answered?

Tags: support, questions, new-users

I was wondering why my question does not get any response.

[How to encapsulate a join or flatten method in linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55712689/how-to-encapsulate-a-join-or-flatten-method-in-linked-list)

Did I do something wrong is there some information missing to make the question findable and searchable?

Also I noticed that my question is not on the Stack Overflow homepage, do you need more reputation to be on the homepage?

Comment: There are 10,000 questions asked per day. There is not enough homepage to show them all ...

Comment: I'm not sure what the consensus is with questions tagged [tag:typescript] but couldn't they benefit from the  tag [tag:javascript] as well?

Comment: That might help, thank you. Just a new user here, sometimes I feel such a noob

Comment: @rene:  Not necessarily.  Just because someone knows JavaScript doesn't imply that they would be the appropriate audience for a TypeScript question.

Comment: Typically the more complex a question is, the longer it will take for (1) a person who knows what you're talking about to see it and (2) format an answer they believe will work.

Comment: @Makoto oh, just like [tag:c] doesn't imply [tag:c++] ...

Comment: @rene:  More like how Java doesn't imply JavaScript. But close enough. :)

Comment: You asked two hours ago.  Have you considered that the developer who knows your answer, and is willing to help, happens to be asleep ATM?

Comment: No sleeping allowed, @Martin! There are homework questions to be answered. Speaking of which, what are you doing on Meta? Those questions aren't going to answer themselves.

Comment: @makoto well actually I'm just listening to the JavaScript tag (and so might others) although I know a bit of TS ...

Comment: Besides what has been said: Stack Overflow is about answering questions *well*, not about answering them *fast*. If it takes a month for a question to be answered properly by the right person, so be it. If you need answers fast, keep researching yourself.

Comment: @Gimby like your name by the way, you are right I should be more patient. Sometimes I feel just like a rich and spoiled celebrity who gets anything he wants right away when I ask it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not everyone is paying attention to every question at every moment in time.  Give it *some* time; someone who is an expert in your subject matter area will show up to help you along.